# Magento 2 - Grunt watch not detecting changes of _extend.less

Tags: magento2, less, grunt, magento2.3.4

I have these files:

> **THEME** = app\design\frontend\company\base

- THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\variables\_typography.less
- THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\variables\_colors.less
- THEME\web\css\source\_extend.less

This is my **THEME\web\css\source\_extend.less**:

```
@import 'lib/extend/variables/_colors';
@import 'lib/extend/variables/_typography';


a { color: @theme__color__primary-alt; }
```

If I make changes in **THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\variables\_colors.less** or **THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\variables\_colors.less** then they are detected by "grunt watch", but if I modify **_extend.less** then "grunt watch" does not react at all.

What might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we are not supposed to add code lines into this file other than imports. There must be an exclude in the **grunt watch** command.

So I created a new file **THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\variables\_test.less** and imported it and moved my changes to it.

**THEME\web\css\source\_extend.less:**

```
@import 'lib/extend/variables/_colors';
@import 'lib/extend/variables/_typography';
@import 'lib/extend/variables/_test';
```

**THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\variables\_test.less**

```
a { color: @theme__color__primary-alt; }
```

Comment: import should have extension file at the end
ex: @import 'lib/extend/variables/_colors.less';

Comment: @mrtuvn, It works without too